# Meaning of "horizontal k-form"

Tags: differential-forms, vector-fields, fiber-bundles

In a paper the following definition is employed:

"Horizontal forms are forms on the total space that vanish when
contracted against one or more vertical vector fields."

I am not that familiar with this notion. So my question: Does contraction of a form with a vector field mean something like taking the trace, i.e.
$$tr(\omega^{i_1, i_2, \dots i_k} v_{i_j})$$?
If so, to which indices does the statement refer? To any choice of an index?

Thanks for any help/advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in more simple terms it is literally "plugging in a (vertical) vector field into the differential form". Given a $k$-form $\omega$ and a vector field $X$, you can define a $(k-1)$-form by
$$
\iota_x\omega(X_1, \dots,X_{k-1}):=\omega(X,X_1,\dots,X_{k-1}).
$$
For horizontal forms $\alpha$, that means if $X$ is any vertical field, we have
$$
\iota_X\alpha(X_1, \dots,X_{k-1})=\alpha(X,X_1,\dots,X_{k-1})=0.
$$
The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product) also does a good job of providing more details as well as any more graduate oriented textbook on differential geometry.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! (I know this operation under the name interior-multiplication.)

Comment: Welcome to differential geometry... :D

Comment: there is some typos, $\iota_X$, and num of vector not the same as defined a $(k-1)$ form, but this doesn't affect much. still +1 :)

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it.